# JavaScript: Sorting with exception

Tags: javascript

Lets say I have an array of objects (for simpler display purposes I will just show it as an array)

`[ 'TEST', 'NEW', 'ALPHA', 'ZOO', 'WHATEVER' ]`

I need to sort it alphabetically (easy part), however, I need to sort it in a way, that a certain word, lets say `NEW` will end up at the very end.

`[ 'ALPHA', 'TEST', 'WHATEVER',  'ZOO', 'NEW' ]`

Here is the function that I sort with

```
var sortedWords = function(a, b) {
    return a.word > b.word ? 1 : -1 ;
};
```

So, I get the sortedWords array, and then go over it again, create a yet another array and push words into the new array, unless the word equals `NEW`. In that case I set it aside and append at the very end of this new array before returning it. There got to be a better and more efficient way of doing this.

Thank you.

Comment: before your return:
`if(a == 'youWord'){return 1;}`

Comment: @BrianHannay Post this as an answer!

Comment: @BrianHannay Remember that if `a` and `b` are both the target word, the result _must_ be 0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change your comparator to look for `NEW` first:

```
function (a, b) {
    if ((a.word === 'NEW') != (b.word === 'NEW')) {
        return a.word === 'NEW' ? 1 : -1;
    }
    return a.word > b.word ? 1 :
           a.word < b.word ? -1 : 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Chris! This does exactly what I needed, but apparently I have to wait for 7 minutes before I can accept this as an answer :)

Comment: @solefald can you check this http://jsfiddle.net/blackjim/X6krQ/ ? Maybe I missed something.

Comment: @Antonis: yep. since you are sorting a flat array (i sort array of objects), you need to change `a.word` to `a` and `b.word` to `b`

Comment: @solefald this is not the code that was submitted though. The initial code didn't work.

Comment: @Antonis: In my original question? See the first line. I mentioned that for simple display purposes I will show it is a flat array. Chris's solution works great in my case, obviously with some adjustments to match my object element names and the words I match for.

Answer (score 4):

[Use sort with a custom compareFunction](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Description)

```
var ar = [ 'ALPHA', 'WHATEVER', 'NEW', 'ZOO', 'TEST' ];

ar.sort(function(a, b){
    var wordToBeLast = 'NEW';  // set your word here
    
    if(a===wordToBeLast){
        return 1;
    } else if(b===wordToBeLast){
        return -1;
    } else {
        return a.localeCompare(b);
    }
});
```

Comment: `return a > b;` is incorrect: the compare function needs to return a number, not a boolean, and the number should be 0 if the two items are equal.

Answer (score 2):

You could define your comparator function as follows:

```
var sortedWords = function(a, b) {
    if (a.word === b.word) {
        // a and b are considered equal, the order is okay
        return 0;   
    }

    if (a.word === "NEW") {
        // "NEW" is considered larger than every other value, the order is wrong
        return 1;
    }

    // Correct order if b equals "NEW", otherwise lexicographical comparison
    return b.word === "NEW" ? -1 : (a.word > b.word ? 1 : -1);
};
```

Comment: Can you explain how this is an answer and not a comment?

Comment: @Blender: I didn't paste my fiddle code at that point of time yet.

Answer (score 0):

There is simpler way using `lodash`, which can be extended to a more complex scenario, while keeping the code simple.

```
const strings = [ 'TEST', 'NEW', 'ALPHA', 'ZOO', 'WHATEVER' ];

_.sortBy(strings, [
    (string) => string !== 'NEW',
    (string) => string
  ])
```